# Opening new fragment from fragment in tab using actionbar - Android

Tags: android, listview, tabs, fragment

I have `ActionBarActivity` with 3 `tabs` in it. In each tab I have `list view`. When I press list view item I want to open new `fragment` with `new list view`. I did this thing with this code:

```
TabCatalogProductsByCategory categories = new TabCatalogProductsByCategory();
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(getFragmentByPosition(0).getId(),categories, "News");                   
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Everything loks fine, the new `fragment` with `list view` appears, but when I click `back button` I can't back to previous fragment, if i click one more time - `ActionBarActivity`closes. I tried to change `transaction.replace()` to `trasaction.add()`, but the results were the same. How can I make my back button work corectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I found answer to my question - https://gist.github.com/andreynovikov/4619215
With litle modifications works perfectly as I want

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand a fragment can't open or manage another fragment it has to be done by your fragment activity. I'd invoke a function in your parent activity to open the new fragment. Look into http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html